# Why nested for loop print its first value irrespective of condition

Tags: python

I'm begineer in python. I'm bit confused about this basic python  program and its output

```
 for num in range(2,10):
 for i in range(2,num):
       if (num % i) == 0:

           break
    else:
       print(num)
```

output

```
 Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit      (Intel)] on win32
 Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
 >>> 
  ================= RESTART: C:\Users\ms\Desktop\python\new.py =================
 2
 3
 5
 7
 >>>
```

As per condition

```
     if (2 %2) == 0:
     break
```

then how 2 prints to the output display

Thanks for helping ..

Comment: Because 2,3,5,7 are prime numbers.

Comment: Could you please fix your indentation to exactly match your actual code? It's not clear what that `else` belongs to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` statement in the inner loop doesn't get executed on the first iteration when `num` is 2 since `range(2, 2)` will return empty sequence. This naturally causes the inner loop to complete thus following `else` statement gets executed.

[Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) has following explanation about `else` in loops:

> Loop statements may have an else clause; it is executed when the loop terminates through exhaustion of the list (with for) or when the condition becomes false (with while), but not when the loop is terminated by a break statement. This is exemplified by the following loop, which searches for prime numbers

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation seems to be wrong. Try the same code with different indentation:

```
for num in range(2,10):
    for i in range(2,num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
           break
        else:
           print(num)
```

In your original code the `else` is aligned with the 2nd `for` loop and not with your `if`.